# Photo Coordinates Vs. World coordinates

Tags: vb.net, 3d, matrix, camera, projection-matrix

I have a Geo-tagged snapshot (photo) captured with a my digital cam.

I want to read world coordinates (real coordinates) upon click on any pixel on this photo.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You mean that you somehow want to determine a "depth" within the photo and calculate the feature's position relative to the GPS coordinates?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. I want to be able to read the real (world coordinates) of any pixel on the photo itself.
Geotag data is just storing only the (capture device)camera position only which can be found in the exif data stored in the image file.

Comment: Well, then you've created a very hard problem. Getting depth cues from a single image is already a non-trivial matter. Then there is the issue of scale (how big is what you see in the image in real-lofe). And not to forget the orientation of your camera. I won't say it's impossible, but at the very least it's very very, hard to a point where you've got to wonder if it's worth it. But perhaps someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: Is this for data you already have, or for data you will capture?  If the latter, you could capture some stereo images (by moving the camera a known distance between two successive shots), and then use the stereo information to estimate depth.  Otherwise, I agree with Bart.  (For example, a pixel could be on a tree next to you or on a mountain 10 miles away.  How do you know?)

Comment: What's your application?  Perhaps some approximations/assumptions are warranted?  Perhaps a semi-automated approach is useful, e.g. assume a depth an orientation, display the result, let user change depth and orientation.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what/how much GPS information your camera is storing in the photo. To actually read the information stored, you can refer to below or other similar articles that show how to read exif data from images using VB:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET-2-0

Comment: Yes, exactly.. I want to be able to read the real (world coordinates) of any pixel on the photo itself. Geotag data is just storing only the (capture device)camera position only which can be found in the exif data stored in the image file.